# Error:cannot access NotNull

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger-2

I encounter the error above when compiling, and it doesn't goes to to any source file. After slowly identify the changes that cause the issue, found out it is apparently the dagger 2 inject is causing issue.

```
@FragmentScope
@Subcomponent
public interface MyComponent {
    void inject(MyJavaFragment myJavaFragment);

    void inject(MyJavaClass myJavaClass);

    void inject(MyKotlinClass myKotlinClass); // <- if change to Java, all works
}
```

I converted MyKotlinClass from Java code to Kotlin, and the error happens. This is in a library, and I already use that in build.gradle

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
```

Why? (note: the app code is originally Java, so I didn't change all to Kotlin yet unless needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long hours of investigation, found out that, the calling Feature to this library, still using the Java Annotation

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
```

But my library is using `kapt` as mentioned in the question above. So that's a clash of annotation processor used, and Java annotation processor is used instead I suspect. By changing the calling library annotation processor to

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
```

would solve the problem. (remember to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` at the top as well)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the case mentioned by Elye, this can also happen when a field annotated with `@Inject` has no corresponding `@Provides` method on a Dagger module, or at least a constructor annotated with `@Inject`

I know there is already a Dagger error complaining about this, but I stumbled accross this today after removing the module with the `@Provides` method and expecting a clean rebuild to tell me what was missing via that error... but I got this error instead.